# Is it a good idea to read over 500GB data from S3 and save the 400GB outputs to S3?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hadoop2, aws-opsworks

My MR job reads 500GB data from AWS S3, in the same time, it saves the intermediate data in S3, and writes the reducers' outputs (around 400GB) to S3, is it a good design?

Are there any other cheaper and stable solutions? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "it saves the intermediate data in S3"? Data between mappers and reducers is normally saved on the local filesystem (I believe) -- how have you configured this to be saved on S3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had our ETL jobs running in AWS. We were using Oozie for workflow management.

When you are running inside EMR (Elastic MapReduce), you have an option to write to either `s3` or to the local `HDFS`.

The decision to store the data in either `s3` or `HDFS` depends on various factors like:

- **Nature of the data**: temporary (use `HDFS`) or permanent (use `s3`)
- **Cost**: storing in `s3` costs you some cents/dollars
- **Bandwidth**: When you upload data to `s3` you consume some bandwidth and AWS charges you for that.
- **Throttling**: Uploads/Downloads to/from `s3` are throttled. If you are uploading/downloading too much of data within a short span of time, then some of your requests may fail. I remember hitting this issue for one of our workflows.
- **Efficiency of jobs**: Storing data in local `HDFS` is faster than storing it in `s3`. So, if you want your jobs to run faster, it may be a good idea to store the results in `HDFS`

In general we followed the guidelines mentioned below:

1. After completing a job in the workflow, if the data is to be consumed by an another job in the workflow, then store it in the local `HDFS` and delete the data after consumption (so that you don't run out of space in `HDFS`).
2. If the data of a particular job is not intended for final consumption (temporary data), then store it in the `HDFS`. Else directly write the output to `s3`.
3. If an intermediate output is needed for final consumption, then directly store the results in `s3`, so that you don't lose the data if the cluster goes down

Since, you could easily run out of space in local HDFS, you need to plan the capacity of your HDFS cluster. The AWS link here [[Calculate the HDFS Capacity of a Cluster]](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-instances.html),  gives guidelines for calculating your HDFS capacity and accordingly determining the size of your EMR cluster.

Comment: Hi Manjunath, thanks for your reply. I'm thinking to store outputs on `local HDFS`, and later push outputs to S3 by `AWS S3` commands. But I'm afraid that the local HDFS on EMR may not have enough space to save so many data, since it's used to run MR job at the same time. Would you please talk a little about how did you store the data in local HDFS? Thank you!

Comment: I have updated the answer. Yes. I agree storing in HDFS could result in space constraints. That's why in my answer, I have mentioned that, you should delete the temporary data as soon as it is no longer needed. However, you can always plan and get the required storage, by requesting appropriate number of Data Node instances. Check this link: docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/…. Check the section: "Calculate the HDFS Capacity of a Cluster".

Answer (score 0):

A map reduce on HDFS is designed to take input and perform few operations and then write.  Since it is done in parallel, the design is not as bad as you were thinking. Can you be more elaborate, about cheaper and stable. HDFS is definitely stable.